# why does import wave produce a figure of a wave and not play wav files

Tags: python, audio, wav, wave

The following link has an example of using python wave to play a wav file.

[pyaudio help play a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951046/pyaudio-help-play-a-file)

The trouble is on my computer any script with 'import wave' just produces a picture of a wave  and does nothing else. (i.e. the rest of the script doesn't even run.) I have no idea why this is.  Is there a way to fix this? I'm running python 2.7 on windows XP.

Comment: What does `import imp`; `print imp.find_module('wave')` show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you have a file called `wave.py` in your current directory (or somewhere in your `PYTHONPATH`) that is run instead of the standard library module of the same name.