# Python 3.5 simple way to play audio

Tags: python-3.x, audio

Oke so for the last week or so i've been looking around for a easy way to play sound files (wav or mp3 doesn't matter).

But alot of the posts i found just did not work or where really old. Does anyone have a simple way to do this wich is not outdated?

i've tryed winsound and pyaudio. pymedia and pygame don't even want to be installed.

i'm so lost becaus this is the thing that holds me back from finishing my code. Also i think this would help alot of starting Python users.

EDIT: i tryed using the code suggested here [pyaudio help play a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951046/pyaudio-help-play-a-file). But this gives me a RIFF id error.

Comment: whats wrong with pyaudio?

Comment: I just find it difficult to use/i never got it to work. If you can point me to a nice example of how to use it that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#example-blocking-mode-audio-i-o) provides the code to play a audio file(.wav).

Edited:

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import sys

CHUNK = 1024

wf = wave.open("Path to audio file", 'rb')

# instantiate PyAudio (1)
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# open stream (2)
stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                rate=wf.getframerate(),
                output=True)

# read data
data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

# play stream (3)
while len(data) > 0:
    stream.write(data)
    data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

# stop stream (4)
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

# close PyAudio (5)
p.terminate()
```

Comment: Where do i put in my path to the file? I don't understand the PYaudio page. Why can it not just be    play("path to file")?

Comment: And if i want to use it inside a program with no input?

Comment: Gives me this error : "File does not start with RIFF ID".

Comment: Are you playing a .wav file?

Comment: [Try](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1m6S1JgmO_WeEJTN3dvNVJnXzQ) try this and check if it works.